# Symfony2 - No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony

I got a task to update a website. This website uses Symfony2. I try to simulate the website on my localhost.

When I try to get to the index page using a empty direction path (REQUEST_URI)
Symfony2 returns `No route found for "GET /"`. The url I try to run is `http://localhost/app_dev.php`.

And when I use (for example) `/booking` it doens't work either

What is wrong ?

app/config/routing.yml :

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

app/config/routing_dev.yml :

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml :

```
AppBundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

AppBundle_booking:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/booking.yml"
    prefix:   /bookings

AppBundle_client:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/client.yml"
    prefix:   /clients

AppBundle_invoice:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/invoice.yml"
    prefix:   /invoices

AppBundle_product:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/product.yml"
    prefix:   /products

AppBundle_category:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/category.yml"
    prefix:   /categories

AppBundle_contracts:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/contract.yml"
    prefix:   /contracts

AppBundle_users:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/user.yml"
    prefix: /users

AppBundle_activities:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/activity.yml"
    prefix: /activities

AppBundle_services:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/service_contract.yml"
    prefix: /services
```

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml :

```
AppBundle_home:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

I know there are a lot of other questions that are similar to mine. But when I try to follow the staps of the given answers it still doesn't work. So i hope this will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `type:     annotation`, so where are your annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **app/config/routing.yml** file you defined **annotation** as your type of routing configuration. However, your are using YML files to configure the routing.

Change your **app/config/routing.yml** to this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml"
```

And the routing configuration for your bundle should be loaded correctly.

Comment: what is weird is that the documentation it's self says its okay if it says annotations... http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes